# Reading system logcat using a script

Tags: logging, aosp

Is it possible to read the android system logcat without connecting the device to the phone using an script or an application.

So i can further extract the data from **logcat** to my Machine learning model

Comment: Accessing the system logcat requires root permissions. Is your device rooted?

Comment: I can test it by rooting, but I need to run this app on others devices to collect data. Is there a work around to get this without rooting?

Comment: No. Because too many apps were snooping on system logcat (a lot of apps print sensitive info in logcat!) Google removed access to logcat from within an app (AFAIR that was introduced with Android 4.4?). Hence to bypass this you need root permissions.

Comment: @Robert Thanks that answers my question.